# Can I send / receive window messages without a window?

Tags: c#, .net, mfc, window-handles

I'm writing a .NET wrapper around an old MFC-based library we have.  It's based around a class that sends notifications using window messages; it has a function that lets the user pass in a handle to a window, and that window will receive the messages.

I could just require the users of my wrapper to subclass `Control` and pass their control's handle in order to receive messages, but that's horrible.  I want my wrapper class to have events which fire whenever the old library sends a message, and then I can do the decoding of the message into something sensible.  But, I don't want my wrapper class to have to be a control.

Is there a way for me to create a 'dummy' window handle, and receive the messages sent to that handle, without creating a window?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a concept of [MessageOnly Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(VS.85).aspx#message_only) which can help you. You may create an internal message only window in your wrapper class and pass this handle to the old library.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a thread with a message pump and sending your messages to that. The thread then raises any necessary events that you want to handle in your C# code.

Answer (score -1):

You can't create a window handle without having a window, since the window handle *is* the window as far Windows is concerned, but you can make a window without the WS_VISIBLE flag set, and use it for message relaying only. I use that technique sometimes to do cross-thread communication in MFC-only applications (don't tell anyone ;) ). You could derive a (c++) class from CWnd, let it process the messages, and call functions or emit signals for every message that is received. I guess that would make it work with your C# code although I don't have experience with that.

Answer (score -3):

To create a window that does not display, but receives messages, use the following code.

The header file:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <afxwin.h>

#define ID_NOTHING_MGS WM_USER + 1001

class control : public CWnd
{
public:
    control();
    LRESULT control::nothing(WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

Function implementation in header file.

```cpp
#include "control.h"

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(control, CWnd)
    ON_MESSAGE(ID_NOTHING_MGS, nothing)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

control::control()
{
    // ref1：https://codeantenna.com/a/s6NmJb6YD8
    // ref2：https://www.cnblogs.com/greatverve/archive/2012/11/04/mfc-message.html
    this->CreateEx(WS_EX_NOACTIVATE, AfxRegisterWndClass(0), _T("windowName"),
        WS_CAPTION | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY,//  | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 400, 350, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

LRESULT control::nothing(WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    MessageBox(TEXT("control receive message"));
    return 0;
}
```

Since control inherit from the CWnd class, it can receive messages。[CreateEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#createex) function，creates the specified window and appends it to the CWnd object. If you do not call CreateEx, the window handle value of the created Control object is 0.

No 'WS_VISIBLE' is used, so the window is not visible.